# Smarty how to get a first index from foreach?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

Construction is this:

```
<!-- projects list -->
            {if !empty($userObjects)}
                <select id="projects-list" tabindex="1" name="project">
                    {if !isset($selected)}<option value="0">Choose project</option>{/if}
                {foreach from=$userObjects item=v}
                    <option value="{$v.Id}" {if $selected==$v.Id}selected="selected"{/if} }>{$v.Name}

                        {* if it's 1st element *}
                        {if $smarty.foreach.v.index == 0}
                            {if isset($limit)}<br /><span id="projlimit">{$limit}</span> {$currency->sign}{/if}
                        {/if}

                    </option>
                {/foreach}
                </select>
```

as you can see I did

```
{if $smarty.foreach.v.index == 0}
```

but it's going wrong. In this case all the `options` elemets has a $limit value. How to make it good? I need only first one.

Comment: v@first or v@index eq 0

When you are inside the foreach you should be using the current loop variable "v" in your case

Comment: Make sense! First is 0 in this case. Oops, my `v` is array, there is no index, maybe `item`?

Comment: though, anyway, even `v` is array in the loop it must be with index, Don't know why it doesn't works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you do this by the array key?

```
{foreach from=$rows key=i item=row}
     {if $i == 0}
         First item in my array
     {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: And if we don't have incremental IDs starting from 0? Then this does not work.

Comment: This is only working for indexed arrays starting from 0.

Answer (score 22):

I don't want to appear rude, but Bondye's answer will not work in all cases. Since PHP's arrays are ordered maps, the value of the first key will not always be 0.

In these cases you can use the `@index`, `@iteration` or `@first` properties. More details are in the smarty `foreach` documentation at  http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration

One of the possible solutions to your question is bellow:

```
{foreach $rows as $row}
    {if $row@iteration == 1}
        First item in my array          
    {/if}            
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Just a notice: This is Smarty 3 syntax. If someone use Smarty 2.x, the answer of cnttlc is (almost) the same as this answer, but in Smarty 2 syntax.

Comment: this is the correct answer, selected one won't work in all cases

Answer (score 14):

You can use this code:

```
{foreach from=$userObjects item=v name=obj}

    {if $smarty.foreach.obj.first}
        This is the first item
    {/if}

    {if $smarty.foreach.obj.last}
        This is the last item.
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to define custom index variable and increment it

Here is my working clean solution:

```
{assign var="index" value=-1}
{foreach from=$myArrObjects item=arrObject}
   {if $index == -1}
      {assign var="index" value=$index+1}
      <!-- Do whatever you want with the index now :) -->
   {/if}    
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty you can use the foreach [`@first`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.first) property to get the first iteration/element. This property **is TRUE if the current {foreach} iteration is the initial one.**

Here is a sample code:

```
{foreach $items as $item}
    {if $item@first}
        this is the first item
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

There are also some other useful foreach properties, like [`@last`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.last) to get the last iteration or [`@total`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.total) to get the total number of iterations.