# how to get the first element of an array which passed to the smarty?

Tags: jquery, smarty

how to get the first element of an array which passed to smarty template page, and treat it some way in smarty page.

i use this way but it's not working.

```
$("item_".{$categories.category_id[1]}).addClass("active");
```

Comment: try `[0]`? no idea if you can actually access elements by index like that in smarty though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smarty how to get a first index from foreach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056545/smarty-how-to-get-a-first-index-from-foreach)

Comment: What you're trying is correct, but try this syntax as well: `$categories.category_id.1` (if 1 is the actual index of your first element, and not 0)

Comment: The smarty tag renders server side so the jquery selector would look like so `$("item_".5)`, which is not valid. You could do it like this instead `$("item_{$categories.category_id[1]}")`. The first element can be accessed like this `{$categories.category_id|reset}` (tested with smarty 3.1.14)

Answer (score 0):

try with concatenating strings with the + operator

For example:

```
var myId = "domElement";
$("#"+myId).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1. replace [1] by .1
2. Write the Smarty variable within the "-quotes.

Result:

```
$("item_{$categories.category_id.1}").addClass("active");
```